# Is there a way to see all "Sponsored Tags"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

Is there a way to see all sponsored tags?

Like the ones [sponsored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) by [adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) or [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook)?

Short of scanning all the tags page, of course.

BTW, I find this way of advertising pretty much aesthetic.

Comment: I also think it's a nice way to show ads.

Comment: I don't mind the sponsored tags, but Please at least make them fit the damn tag box.  Currently it looks like a blind yak edited the html to put in the sponsors.

Comment: Any news about this after 10 years ? Is it still "on the to-do list" ?

Answer (score 8):

We need a new Super Ninja search option: `sponsored:1`

Comment: Then I'd need a way to see all the Super Ninja search options. Having accomplished that, I'd need a way to see all the ways to see all the Super Ninja search options which showed me all the sponsored tags. Having done that....

Comment: Meta.SuperNinja.com/domainoverflow

Answer (score 5):

No, but it really should. I really like this kind of sponsoring. Branding without disturbing. Companies that understands that should be honored with some kind of listing or search-option.

One easy solution is to add an extra tab (or link) under 'Tag'-page. The listing could be a really simple one, only the sponsors and their tags. I think that would be a great way to show us who the sponsors are and in a way thank them for supporting the community, Jeff and everyone else that benefits from their money.

Answer (score 4):

A "sponsor gallery" is on the to-do list... I suppose we could list the tags that are sponsored under the copy. So like...

> [Adobe Logo] - Flash and Flex provide .... (more copy)...
>     
> *sponsored tags:* [flash], [flex],...

Maybe we'll get to it in Oct some time....

Answer (score 1):

A list of them would suffice, IMHO. I don't see any need at all to have some sort of search method to only bring back sponsored tags.

Comment: But who's going to maintain the list?

Comment: This is why we have things like Community Wiki and FAQs